# My GridView control bound to a SqlDataSource does not update

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, gridview, sqldatasource

All the data is displayed correctly. Only the "Update" link isn't working. My code is:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection %>"
        DataSourceMode="DataReader" ID="DataFrom"
        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM Classes" DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM Classes WHERE Id=@Id"
        UpdateCommand="UPDATE Classes SET Password=@Password, Name=@Name WHERE Id=@Id">
        <DeleteParameters><asp:Parameter Name="Id" /></DeleteParameters>
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Id" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Password" Type="String" /><asp:Parameter Name="Name" Type="String" />
        </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="Main" DataSourceID="DataFrom" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowSorting="True" DataKeyNames="Id,Password,Name"
        AutoGenerateDeleteButton="True" AutoGenerateEditButton="True" AutoGenerateSelectButton="False">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Class ID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Password" HeaderText="Password" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: What "Update" link?  Could you post it as well?

Comment: I meant the auto generated update link in the GridView after clicking "Edit."

Answer (score 2):

You must take care of below points:

- The GridView & hence the DataSource never allows changing of the Columns which are specified in `DataKeyNames` property.
- Don't try to update a PrimaryKey column. This will not be allowed. Although No error will be shown on clicking update, but if you check the values in Database, changes aren't applied.
- Make sure your Update command is not trying to set a  NEW value for Primary key. as a result, complete Update command will be rejected if you even try to set a Primary Key. i.e. even other Non- Primary key columns will  not  be changed. So if `Id` is a primary Key, below update command will be rejected if you specify new value for `Id`:

  UpdateCommand="UPDATE Classes SET Id=@Id,Password=@Password,Name=@Name WHERE Id=@Id"

So in your case, I guess, `Id` must be a primaryKey. set the property DataKeyNames as:

```
DataKeyNames="Id".
```

Because, you want to update Name & Password, so don't include them in DataKeyNames. What's important  is that usually you should mention only the PrimaryKeys in `DatKeyNames` property.

Rest of Your UpdateCommand is completely fine.

Comment: Note: changing the update command to "UPDATE Classes SET Password='newPass', Name=@Name WHERE Id=@Id" correctly updates the Password to newPass.

Comment: Hey human44, I have edited my answer. Please check now. Thank you for your reply.